# Heap down - What is math logic and intuition behind $\sum_{i=1}^{\log n}(\log n - i) \times 2^i $

Tags: algorithms, heaps

In heap (bubble down) we have the formula :
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \sum_{i=1}^{\log n}(\log n - i)\times 2^i & = & \log n\sum_{i=1}^{\log n}2^i -\log n\sum_{i=1}^{\log n}i\times2^i \\
& = & \log n\times2^{\log n+1}-(\log n\times2^{\log n+1}-(2^{\log n+1}−2)) \\
& = & 2n−2\in Θ(n) 
\end{eqnarray*}

1. Why we have $\sum_{i=1}^{log(n)}(\log n - i)\times2^i$ ?
2. How we get to $2−2\in Θ()$ ?

Please explain details!

Answer (score 1):

So I guess you are showing that a complete binary tree can be made a heap in linear time.

1. $(\log n - i)$
   counts the maximum number of swaps that a node may require, starting at level $i$, and descending to its final level; at most it could become a leaf. For instance if it starts at level $0$, then it could possibly require $\log n$ swaps; this would happen if the node placed at the root position becomes a leaf, since $\log n$ is the full height of the binary tree. And since level $i$ has up to $2^i$ nodes, $(\log n - i)2^i$ counts the maximum number of swaps for all nodes from level $i$, and $\sum\limits_i (\log n - i)2^i$ counts the maximum number of swaps for all nodes in the tree.
2. $2n-2$ is asymptotically $\leq 2n$ and $\geq n$; for instance $n\geq 2$ suffices. This is exactly [the definition of $\Theta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations).